# how to stop wiggling (jumping) list menu item on mouse over?

Tags: css, user-interface, border

I have menu when I mouseover `li` is wiggling little bit. How stop that wiggling.

code is here
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gg03Lam/)

Comment: Post your code in your question as required. -1 removed after you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get rid of that is to modify the css like this:

```
.inner LI {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.25em 1.75em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to remove the shaking on hover. To do that remove the border

```
.inner LI:hover {
    background: #eee;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

This would be the code that needs changing. If you really want the border style, add box-shadow instead to achieve the same effect.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The wiggling property is because of the border added while there is an `:hover` event on the `.inner li`

**Correct CSS:**

```
.inner LI:hover { background: #eee;  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

***Code updated:*** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/5gg03Lam/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Line 59 in Index.html change from:

```
    .inner LI:hover 
    { 
      border: 1px solid #ddd; 
      background: #eee; 
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

to:

```
    .inner LI:hover 
    { 
      background: #eee; 
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.inner LI:hover` class, you have set `border: 1px solid #ddd;`.

However, your `.inner LI` class has no border, or 'a border of 0px'.

To remedy this situation, try adding `border: 1px solid transparent;` to your `.inner LI` class.